# Overwrite function temporarily

Tags: r, methods

I want to provide a function called "Sdt" in my package. There are multiple methods of it, but they all lead to Sdt.default(a, b, c, d), which returns a named vector with some calculated stuff for a,b,c and d.

But in some cases the user of my package needs to extend Sdt.default, for example, if he/she wants to try out some other calculations with the four variables.

So I thought: Why not temporarily overwrite the function? So I tried something like this (with Sdt of course, but this is a better toy example):

```
a <- function() print("FUNCTION A CALLED")
b <- function() print("FUNCTION B CALLED")
c <- function() a()
d <- function(){

  a()
  a <- b
  a()

  c()
}
d()
```

The outcome looks like

```
[1] "FUNCTION A CALLED"
[1] "FUNCTION B CALLED"
[1] "FUNCTION A CALLED"
```

But I want to have

```
[1] "FUNCTION A CALLED"
[1] "FUNCTION B CALLED"
[1] "FUNCTION B CALLED"
```

The "<<-" operator would work in this example, but if a() is defined within a  package it would throw error messages, ("determined function within a package can't be altered" or something like that)

TL;DR
How to override from global environment a function within a package temporarily but completly, so all following and nested calls use the altered function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a fan of @DavidArenburg's solution, but if defining default arguments for all of the variables you want to temporarily override isn't an option, this is another way:

```
d <- function(){
  a()
  a <- b
  a()
  environment(c) <- environment()
  c()
}
d()
# [1] "FUNCTION A CALLED"
# [1] "FUNCTION B CALLED"
# [1] "FUNCTION B CALLED"
c()
# [1] "FUNCTION A CALLED"
```

Comment: Awesome! This seems to work perfectly- thank you! Now I just have to test, if this leads to strange behaviour in my code, but the first proof of concept seems to work as aspected. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use neither `assign` or `<<-`. I would just modify `c()` function

```
a <- function() print("FUNCTION A CALLED")
b <- function() print("FUNCTION B CALLED")
c <- function(x = a) x() 
d <- function(){

  a()
  a <- b
  a()

  c(a)
}
d()

## [1] "FUNCTION A CALLED"
## [1] "FUNCTION B CALLED"
## [1] "FUNCTION B CALLED"
```

While `c()` without a parameter will work the same

```
c()
## [1] "FUNCTION A CALLED"
```

Comment: You have a point, it's kinda dirty. But thats exactly what I was trying to avoid: My code makes heavy use of the function I want to override, and add an optional parameter to **every** sub function, and document all that... That's a PITA. But I will have your answer in mind, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`assign`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assign.html) function to put your newly created function into the global environment.
Have a look at this example replacing base `sum` function :

```
callSum <- function() sum(1)

main <- function(){

  # here we use the original sum function -> we expect 1
  print(sum(1))

  # let's create a new sum function returning always 100
  # and assign it to the global env. with name "sum"
  # (note that the name of this function object is not important, 
  # but the name used in assign is crucial)
  newSum <- function(v) {return(100)}
  assign("sum", newSum, envir=globalenv())

  # let's call sum(1) -> we expect 100
  print(sum(1))

  # let's call a function that calls sum(1) -> we expect 100
  print(callSum())

  # we don't want to return anything...
  invisible()
}

main()
```

it prints:

```
[1] 1
[1] 100
[1] 100
```

---

However, this is not really a clean solution.

If you think you need to switch between the package implementation and a custom implementation very often, I suggest to create a wrapper of `Std` and use it wherever you want to use the `Std` function. In this way, when you want to stop using the package version, you just have to change the wrapper implementation, e.g. :

```
StdWrapper <- function(a,b,c,d){
   return(Std(a,b,c,d))
   # return(YourCustomStd(a,b,c,d))

   # as soon as you need to switch to a custom implementation,
   # just comment the first line and uncomment the second and vice-versa 
}
```

Comment: Added a cleanest possibility ;)

Comment: This is a good idea, but in my case it's the other way round: I **provide** the package. I need to give the user a chance, to override my the Sdt()-function, to force the whole package to work with it. I tried to use your solution, but all functions within the package seem to use the Sdt() from within the package. The wrapper you suggested is fine if the user has access to the source-code, but I want to avoid that. Thank you for your thoughts! :)